# file object always returning null in controller

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to upload two files using ajax but in mvc5 controller its always returning null. bellow i have provided code which i have written. please check and tell me whats wrong i am doing here. Two file class name is: `Banner` and another is `Thumbnail` i only added code for Thumbnail to make example smaller.

mvc5 controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Add(Add data)
        {

}
```

model:

```
public class Add
    {
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase Thumbnail { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase Banner { get; set; }
    }
```

ajax:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("Thumbnail", $('#Thumbnail')[0].files[0]);//check this line carefully. i think something wrong here

     $("#add").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/MyCon/Add',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function (data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    swal({
                        title: "Successful!",
                        text: "New product has been created.",
                        icon: "success",
                        button: "Ok",
                    });
                    setTimeout(
                        function () {
                            location.reload();
                        }, 3000);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    //console.log(error);
                    swal({
                        title: "Error!",
                        text: "Failed! Something wrong..",
                        icon: "error",
                        button: "Ok",
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="Thumbnail">Thumnail:</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="Thumbnail">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your uploaded file is appended to your form_data?

Because as the code snippet you're showing here the appending script is not being wrapped by any events. This means it will immediately run when you load the post. Which is lead to append `undefined` value to your controller.

Maybe you should move `form_data.append("Thumbnail", $('#Thumbnail')[0].files[0]);` this script here into file input onChange EventListener or into add button onClick EventListener

e.g :

```
$('#Thumbnail').on('change', function() {
    form_data.append("Thumbnail", $('#Thumbnail')[0].files[0]);
});
```

or

```
$("#add").on("click", function () {
    form_data.append("Thumbnail", $('#Thumbnail')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        ......//normal ajax
    });
});
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: hay man! you saved my day! Basically this was the case. I should move it under on click. Thanks a lot